# Converting and Passing in an Array of Numbers Using MongoDB `$in` Operator

Tags: arrays, mongodb

In my MongoDB/Node backend I am taking in passed-in parameters and then filtering on some data.

The first thing I do is take in string values (that happen to represent numbers) such as "1", "2", etc. and turn them into a comma-separated array.

Now I need to filter on a property called "responsibilitySequence". The thing is, the values for this property are of type "number", not "string".

So how do I adjust the following function so that what gets passed-in as an array that Mongo will evaluate using the `$in` operator, consists of numbers, not string values?

```
  if (responsibilitySequence) {
    let arrResponsibilitySequence = [];
    arrResponsibilitySequence = responsibilitySequence.split(",");
    _.each(arrResponsibilitySequence, (l, key, c) => {
      arrResponsibilitySequence[key] = new RegExp(arrResponsibilitySequence[key], "i");
    });
    search.responsibilitySequence = {
      $in: arrResponsibilitySequence
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just map the values and parse them as `int`:

```
  if (responsibilitySequence) {
    let arrResponsibilitySequence = responsibilitySequence.split(",");
    search.responsibilitySequence = {
      $in: arrResponsibilitySequence.map(x => Number.parseInt(x)) // or just +x
    };
  }
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks so much, @Akrion!